# Authorize all assets in an SPA

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to prevent access to any npm/Angular assets in an SPA from being served.  I created this using the Angular dotnet template.  I just can't seem to find the right recipe.

[Authentication and authorization for SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

That's the closest I can get.  But there's problems.  It allows access to a login/logout controller.  I just want the app to load only if there's an authenticated user.  Otherwise redirect to an OAuth2 server with a JWT token and provide that token to my SPA.

Comment: Where are you hosting the Angular app?

Comment: In Asp.net core Angular application, the static file was stored in the `wwwroot` folder, to serve static files based on authorization, you can store them outside of wwwroot, call UseStaticFiles, specifying a path, after calling UseAuthorization, Set the fallback authorization policy. More detail information, see [Static file authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#static-file-authorization).

Comment: "It allows access to a login/logout controller. I just want the app to load only if there's an authenticated user." About this issue, since it is a new issue, you'd better create a new thread, please don't ask multiple problems in one thread. For the login page it should be anonymous, and everyone can access it to login. If you want to change the login page, you need to change the login url. Refer to [Configuration through code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-7.0#other-configuration-options).